# Developer account under 18

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

I'm 16 and I've learned to develop iOS apps recently.

I've finished my first app yesterday and I want to upload it to the App Store.

I've tried to register with my name and my father's credit card and I got the verification code from Apple. But when I'm trying to sign in to my account I get this error message:

> We are unable to activate your Apple Developer Program membership.
>   We have received your purchase information and will email you shortly to verify additional details.

Additionally, I'm trying to reach Apple Developer Support for over an hour but they don't answer the phone.

Any idea what can I do with that?

Comment: What makes you think that your age is the problem?

Comment: @patrix According to Apple Developer Center, you need to be at least 18 to register

Comment: @Yahllilevy Still, if you used your dad's name, birthday, and credit card I can't see how Apple could somehow know it's not really him.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I've used my name with my dad's credit card, because I want the developer name on the App Store will be my name

Comment: @Yahllilevy That could be your problem right there, usually names on the credit cards and credit card numbers need to match. Can't you use your name with your dad's billing info? I don't know, as I've never applied for an Developer License, but would be interested in hearing the answer to this, as I intend to soon, also being a young dev, one year younger than you are.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I know, but if I don't have a credit card, how can I enroll with my dad's?

Comment: @Yahllilevy I was editing my post when before I got your response, I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the activation email — there's nothing else you can do and trying to contact anyone else until then may cause confusion. You used a different name than the name on the card used to purchase the membership, so you will need to complete another activation step. This seems to be manually initiated and you need to wait for the email, which may take up to two weeks.

You will be given further instructions which may include information on cancelling the membership and being instructed to pay using a card with your own name, which was the final resolution in my case.

Comment: I've already got 4 emails: "Order Acknowledgement', "Your order is being processed", "Apple Developer Product Activation Code" and "Your Apple invoice # NUMBER", should I wait for more?